# shift keys stop Eclipse incremental search

Tags: eclipse

There's the weirdest things with my new netbook.

I start increment search in Eclipse with ctrl-j, any press on one of the 2 shift keys with a combination of another keys interrupts the search and insert the character, which makes searching words with a combination of lower case/upper characters case very difficult (I can still use CapsLock)

Using Eclipse 3.8.1 under ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Its working fine in **Eclipse Standard/SDK Version: Luna Service Release 2(4.4.2) Build id: 20150219-0600 Ubuntu 14.04**

Answer (score 0):

shift-left+shift-right key combination shortcut for keyboard layout switching was somehow interfering with Eclipse.